Maya python: How to select last keyframe of an animated object?
I'm new in scripting and I'm trying to code a simple script in maya which gonna grab first and last keyframe of an object and will set it to tangent and set to infinity.
import maya.cmds as cmds
#set first key
cmds.keyTangent(index = (0,0), inTangentType='spline', outTangentType ='spline') 
#I was trying to grab last keyframe knowing that in array it will be -1
cmds.keyTangent(index = ([-1]), inTangentType='spline', outTangentType ='spline')

cmds.setInfinity(postInfinite='linear', preInfinite='linear')

I'm specifically looking for a way to grab LAST keyframe, but couldn't find a way do this online.

Does this answer your question? Get Animation start and end keyframes in Maya Standalone (No User Interface)
